# Event Handler triggers System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, event-handling, stack-overflow

Code:

```
 private void addExcel(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        if (!textBox.Text.Contains('!'))
        {
            textBox.Text += "!";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(textBox.Text);
        sb.Remove(textBox.Text.IndexOf('!'), 1);
        textBox.Text = sb.ToString();
 }
```

[image]

The exception occurs in `sb.ToString();`
This application is supposed to calculate factorials.

Comment: Hi Ray. Consider adding the entire method to your code example, and let us know what event triggers it. I think I have the answer below but editing this would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that this is called in your `TextBox.TextChanged` event. When this happens :`textBox.Text = sb.ToString();`
It adds a `string` with no "!" to the textbox, which is then changed, which then triggers the event, which then:

```
if (!textBox.Text.Contains('!'))
        {
            textBox.Text += "!";
        }
```

adds a "!", which then triggers the event where it is removed again. FOREVAR!

Your best bet is to assign `sb.ToString()` to another variable, other than textbox.